# If user in session, copies and pastes url in another window, the app should get logged out

Tags: security, url, session, browser, logout

I am working on a financial web application.

There is a client requirement that if user is logged in and already browsing the app. If he copies and pastes the browser url to another window. In another window, the user should get logged out.

I know http is stateless and there is no inbuilt browser mechanism (cookies etc) to solve it, this needs to be implemented by programming only. I guess people have already solved this problem. Do you know know possible solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no solution.

The browser keeps the cookies and all of the user informations for all the Tabs & Windows you open. It will clear the datas (like cookies that ask to be removed after the session) as soon as you close ALL tabs and windows of your browser. Note that if the user use another browser, the behaviour your want will be respected — browsers dnn't (yet ?) share this kind of informations.

It is simply not possible to solve the problem with code, and you'll have to find work-around.

As a researcher, I've seen one of these solutions : de-auth the user on the HTTP_REFERER (Apache Env. Variable). As soon as the referer was not the application itself (except for the login form), the user was de-authed. But take care of it : the Referer is an info sent by the browser. And no information sent by the browser should be trusted :). The advice remains, if only you want to use Javascript. You'll find someone to use a JS-disabled-browser to bypass your verification.

That's why Application Development is not yet dead ;)

Cheers.
K.